# Updating a pivot table in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I've got a many to many relationship between a `student` and an `institution_contact`.

`student`s should only ever have two `institution_contact`s and I have an attribute on the pivot table named `type` to be set as 1 or 2.

So, my pivot table looks like this:
`institution_contact_student: id, institution_contact_id, student_id, type`

I've run into difficulty in deciding how to approach the issue of adding/updating the pivot table. Let's say I have 100 students and I want to assign them a contact with the type of 1.

My current solution is to delete the contact then add it:

```
$students = Student::all(); // the 100 students
$contactId = InstitutionContact::first()->id; // the contact

foreach ($students as $student) {
    // remove existing contact
    $student
        ->institutionContacts()
        ->newPivotStatement()
        ->where('type', 1)
        ->delete();

    // add new contact
    $student
        ->institutionContacts()
        ->attach([$contactId => ['type' => 1]]);
}
```

However, I'm thinking that this is going to hit the database twice for each student, right? So would I be better off creating a model for the pivot table and removing all entries that matched the student id and the type then simply adding the new ones? Or would creating a model for the pivot table be considered bad practice and is there a better way of accomplishing this that I've missed?

Please note the reason I'm not using sync is because I'm relying on the type attribute to maintain only two contacts per student. I'm not aware of a way to modify an existing pivot without causing issues to my two contacts per student requirement.

Edit:

Instead of creating a model I could run the following code to perform the delete using `DB`.

```
DB::table('institution_contact_student') // the pivot table
    ->whereIn('student_id', $studentIds)
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->delete();
```

Comment: If I had a model for the pivot the delete process could be done in one go using `whereIn` for the `student_id` however for the insert you're right it would be one per student, but at least it's knocked down by half right?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then you can use the updateExistingPivot method for updating your pivot table.But first of course you have to define the pivot in your relationship. For instance,

```
public function institutionContacts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('institutionContact')->withPivot('type');
}
```

after this, all you have to do is use the following code:

```
$student
       ->institutionContacts()
       ->updateExistingPivot($contactId, ["type" => 1]);
```

Hope this helps.